# Blurred screenshots in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please refer to the link to see what kind of screenshots I get - http://goo.gl/uDIyf3 instead of http://goo.gl/BQy1hI .

Not sure what could be wrong here as the same code has been working for me on other machines. The only possibility that I see is an issue with the configuration on the machine but can't find what that issue is.

The same scripts when ran in IE, it renders the correct screenshot, so it could be a chrome specific issue. Have uninstalled & reinstalled chrome but still the same.

I am using Selenium 2.28.0 version.

Please let me know if anyone needs more inputs my issue. Any hint to resolve this would be really helpful.

Have posted the same question on sqa as well - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9535/blurred-screenshots-with-selenium-webdriver
Thanks

Comment: That's really interesting... Could you try to use latest chromedriver version?

Comment: @sap1ens, I am using the latest version - 2.10

Answer (score -1):

I'm seeing this problem too. Here's the method that takes the snapshot. The same code works on IE9 but produces the mirrored screenshot on Chrome.

```
def screenSnapshot(self):
    try:
        if self.__snapshot_dir:
            self.__WD.get_screenshot_as_file(os.path.join(
                self.__snapshot_dir,
                "screenshot-{}.png".format(time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))))
            return(True)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: {}".format(str(e)))
    return(False)
```

I'm using a remote webdriver. The node is running Windows 7 Enterprise with Service Pack 1 installed.

Any other suggestions I could try? I have the latest Chrome driver too.